# Unsigned Char String

Tags: c++, c

How does one identify a string as an unsigned char string?

e.g. something like this is what I had in mind

```
unsigned char* ucstr = U"\x10\x12\x14\x16";
```

Is there an identifier like the `U` I placed? Or must I cast it?

Comment: U is unicode...

Comment: i actually just noticed that. consider it a coincidence

Comment: Pick one language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) is the best you can get. Since none exists make your own! You can then do your `reinterpret_cast` to get the correct type.

```
const unsigned char* operator""_u (const char* bytes)
{
   return reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Can you template this for other types? e.g. `template<typename T>const unsigned char*operator""_u(const T*src){return reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(src);}`

Comment: Also, this code posted doesn't look like it works :/

Comment: `const unsigned char* operator""_u (const char* bytes, std::size_t){   return einterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(bytes);}` some compilers require the size to be given... and there is a lot of restrictions on the arguments so you may not be able to use a template // Also tested this code snippet on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh) with your example string and it prints to console =)

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't work for me because size is required :) thanks

Comment: @ChrisMc the size parameter is required for string literals, that is part of the definition.

Comment: @CryptographyMan user-defined literals can't be templated for multiple types until C++20. Until them, you'll have to use overloads instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no prefix for declaring a string literal that uses `unsigned char` characters. Just use a normal `char`-based string literal and type-cast a pointer to it, eg:

```
const unsigned char * ucstr = (const unsigned char *) "\x10\x12\x14\x16";
```

Or

```
const unsigned char * ucstr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>("\x10\x12\x14\x16");
```

Comment: @H.S. With C and `"\x10\x12\x14\x16"`, the last `char `is `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

C has *compound literals*:

```
(unsigned char []) { "string" }
```